# Event Hub Batch Publishing using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, azure, mqtt, azure-eventhub

We are working on a problem where we need to send a large number of events/messages ( read ~ 1,000,000 messages in <5 seconds). After a good amount of research we thought it might be a configuration issue wherein the the Throughput Units and Partitions divisions is the key to achieve the target. However, after using Event Hubs at a maxed out configuration, we were still not able to achieve the desired target.

We have followed the code examples from official Microsoft documents but there was significant data loss. At this point of time we don't really know if it is a configuration issue or issue in our code keeping in mind we are following official Microsoft instructions.

Any suggestions on this would be really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: How is the event hub configured in terms of Partitions  and Throughput Units?
How big is the payload of the messages? What is the available bandwith? Any measurements to share?

Comment: We had assigned 10 TUs (w/ Auto Inflate to 20 turned ON).For partitions we assigned it 10 as well, however we are not reading the event hub data partition-wise per se. The order doesn't really matter here for us . The payload that we are sending is a JSON message with 3 to 4 key value pairs.

Comment: how many senders do you have? Is it just one process that is sending all those events?

Comment: It would be helpful if you shared some code demonstrating the pattern that you're using for configuring clients and publishing.  A representative sample of your payload would also be helpful.   Can you also share the tier of your Event Hubs namespace?

Comment: @PeterBons . For testing purpose we are simulating the events using a single script. However for the real scenario, senders can go up to 100,000.

Comment: *For testing purpose we are simulating the events **using a single script.*** -> that might be the bottleneck.

Comment: @PeterBons do you suggest we try and split senders to multiple scripts?

Comment: Yes, the ingestion capacity of event hub is very, very large but a single sender is probably not fast enough the make use of it.

Comment: Thanks, @PeterBons. I will try this out update how it turns out.

Comment: Hi, @PeterBons, We tried splitting the sender but it wasn't much successful either. We encountered the same issue of data loss.

Comment: Are there any metrics shown in the azure portal that indicate errors?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233326/discussion-between-nr75-and-peter-bons).